# MacBook Pro mid 2014, Bluetooth upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, big-sur

I have MacBook Pro 15inch mid 2014, https://support.apple.com/kb/sp704
It works still fine after all these years. Only problem now is that I use my AirPods Pro with it. It works fine for music of video's. With with calling or zoom meetings the quality is very bad. This is a problem with the Bluetooth chip, its 4.0.
Is it a possibility to use a Bluetooth 4.2 or 5.0 dongle and disable the internal one? And can somebody recommend a dongle?

Comment: What makes you think the problem on the Zoom mtgs is cause by the 'bluetooth chip'?

Comment: Because the limitation of the chip. When the microphone of my AirPods gets active the output of the AirPods is limited to only 8000hz. I did read this is a limitation of Bluetooth 4.0.

Comment: See if [this setup video](https://youtu.be/95TYH2UL7qw) helps.  I saw many comments on the Apple Support boards that said this was helpful in getting AirPods to work with Zoom.

Comment: This issue seems to be related to protocol limitations, reducing the quality to Mono 8.0 kHz whenever the mic is used (https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/282705/62173). However, this issue does not occur when connecting the AirPods to bluetooth-5.0 iPhones or iPads. — **Did you find a working dongle for the MacBook Pro 2014, Hamkaastosti?** — I've tried the Asus BT-500, but it did not work for me (https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/416386/62173).

Comment: To confess, I did give up. I now use the internal mic in my MacBook and then I can use my AirPods as speaker only at 48kHz. But if you find something working, please tell me